# How to fix a spacing issue in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a database of `Artists/Performers` and there talents I use grep and sed to pull the info of a particular artist which outputs to a predesigned text file for distribution when the performer performs at a venue. My issue is the output file has a design border around the edge depending on the length of the name it will put the border out of line the width of the space is 55 spaces from the start of the artists name.Getting the info isnt the problem its the formatting of the line as not to disturb the border.

This is what I use at the moment

```
sed -i "s/{artist}/$artist/" $filename
```

At the moment the border line is inconsistent based on the varying length of the artist name.

The output shows like this at the moment:

```
 Û  °  Artist ... : Don Stevens                                            Û
 Û  °  Talent ... : Singer                                              Û
 Û  °                                                                   Û
```

It needs to be like this:

```
 Û  °  Artist ... : Don Stevens                                         Û
 Û  °  Talent ... : Singer                                              Û
 Û  °                                                                   Û
```

Comment: @C0BRa Please provide more information like a sample of database and what your actual output and expected output.

Comment: Please, provide concrete examples of the processed files and the output to better explain the case.

Comment: Use monospace font or some tool like `column`

Comment: Should there be a space before first `Û`?

Comment: no space before first Û

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `printf` you can specify the width.
When the whitespace is made with spaces, use

```
sed  "s/{artist}[ ]*/$(printf '%-55s' "${artist}")/" "$filename"
```

When you might have other whitespace, try the `-r` option:

```
sed -r "s/\{artist\}\s*/$(printf '%-55s' "${artist}")/" "$filename"
```

Comment: Many thanks just needed a small edit to fit my needs added -i after sed.